# ChartJS radar scale points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a radar chart showing (nearly) as I want it. The only problem is that the scale should go up to 20 but, as you can see below, the highlighted point is 17 and is off the chart. How do I scale it so that the max point would be 20 and the shown highlighted point would be inside the chart?

[image]

The current code I have is:

```
var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["ATT", "SPD", "POW", "DEF", "STA", "TEC"],
    datasets: [ {
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 5,
        scaleStepWidth: 5,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        pointLabelFontSize: 16,
        fillColor: "rgba(0,120,0,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(0,120,0,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(10,10,10,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#ccc",
        pointHighlightFill: "#333",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(255,255,0,1)",
        data: [12,15,17,16,11,13] 
    } ] 
};
```

I thought it would be the `scaleSteps`, `scaleStepWidth` and `scaleStartValue` options that would change this, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

**EDIT:** It doesn't seem to affect another set of data...

[image]

As you can see here the value of 17 does sit within the chart. The code for this one is:

```
var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["ATT", "SPD", "POW", "DEF", "STA", "TEC"],
    datasets: [ {
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 5,
        scaleStepWidth: 5,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        pointLabelFontSize: 16,
        fillColor: "rgba(0,120,0,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(0,120,0,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(10,10,10,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#ccc",
        pointHighlightFill: "#333",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(255,255,0,1)",
        data: [19,17,15,6,16,15] 
    } ] 
};
```

What is the difference between the 2? The second one has a value of 19 for `ATT` but it sits within the chart just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that I needed to move the `scaleSteps`, `scaleStepWidth` and `scaleStart` to the declaration of the new `Radar` chart as below, rather than in the dataset.

```
window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("radarCanvas").getContext("2d");
window.myRadar = new Chart(ctx).Radar(radarChartData, {
responsive: false,
    pointDot:false,
    showTooltips: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 4,
    scaleStepWidth: 5,
    scaleStartValue: 0
}); }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7p8ffvqx/ for the working example.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me :)