# Add custom data scale to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using a basic chart in Chart.js - I'd like to know if it would be possible to use a **custom scale** on my axis, so for example I want my data points to be plotted on a 0-10 data scale. Is this possible?

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Staying well", "Looking after yourself", "Where you live", "Feeling safe and being listened to", "Making decisions and managing money", "How you feel"],

        datasets: [{
            label: "Careplan",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            data: [5, 8, 9, 4, 6, 6, 5]
        }]
    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my question and answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394207/chartjs-radar-scale-points)

You need to set the `scaleSteps`,`scaleStepWidth` and `scaleStartValue`. In the above example it is:

```
scaleSteps: 4,
scaleStepWidth: 5,
scaleStartValue: 0
```

Which added to a total of 20 with 4 lines through. You can play about with these values to get your desired effect.

Comment: What's the best way to use two charts in different places, would I need to change the ctx and canvas id/variables?

Comment: Possibly needs another question, but yes, you would need to replicate your steps, but name the variables differently.